Keyboard overlaps content in Jetpack Compose
I cannot do it.
My manifest is like this:
<activity
        android:name=".app.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

My Composable like this:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        HeadLineLarge(
            idRes = R.string.lblLogIn,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 32.dp)
        )

        SomeTextFieldsHere()

        PrimaryButton(
            idString = R.string.btnLogIn,
            onClick = {

            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.75f)
        )
    }
}

And I'm trying to display de button over de keyboard. How can i do it?

You can do it by adding offset to bottom of Button as big current keyboard height. You can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79225695/5457853
